# How to parse the below json into complex table structure as below using ng-repeat

Tags: json, angularjs

`

[Table Image Link](https://httpsimage.com/v2/be1edefd-1caa-40ff-bb43-2823d7d4954c.png)

[image]

`I have a table structure as in the attached image and my json structure is like this

I could able to form the table upto locations but not able to access the router details as i am not getting the scope of the location variable

This JSON looks complex to me and cant able to get the scope of the varaible for framing the table structure as required. I tried forming table inside the table also but in that also scope is not available as the inner table tag gets ended up

Please help me to form the table structure

```
[
    {
        "regionName": "Australia",
        "locations": [
            {
                "locationname": "sydney",
                "routers": [
                    {
                        "routername": "S1",
                        "installed": "1",
                        "provisioned": "1",
                        "delata": "2",
                        "maximum": "2"
                    },
                    {
                        "routername": "S2",
                        "installed": "1",
                        "provisioned": "2",
                        "delata": "2",
                        "maximum": "2"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "locationname": "Honkong",
                "routers": [
                    {
                        "routername": "H1",
                        "installed": "1",
                        "provisioned": "8",
                        "delata": "6",
                        "maximum": "9"
                    },
                    {
                        "routername": "Hungeri",
                        "installed": "1",
                        "provisioned": "6",
                        "delata": "5",
                        "maximum": "9"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "regionName": "India",
        "locations": [
            {
                "locationname": "Banglore",
                "routers": [
                    {
                        "routername": "T1",
                        "installed": "1",
                        "provisioned": "9",
                        "delata": "5",
                        "maximum": "4"
                    },
                    {
                        "routername": "T2",
                        "installed": "1",
                        "provisioned": "6",
                        "delata": "5",
                        "maximum": "9"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "locationname": "Mumbai",
                "routers": [
                    {
                        "routername": "M1",
                        "installed": "1",
                        "provisioned": "6",
                        "delata": "6",
                        "maximum": "9"
                    },
                    {
                        "routername": "M2",
                        "installed": "1",
                        "provisioned": "6",
                        "delata": "5",
                        "maximum": "9"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

This is what i have tried

```
 <table>
      <thead>
        <th> Regions </th>
        <th> Location </th>
        <th> Routers </th>
      </thead>
      <tbody ng-repeat="regions in finalJson">
            <tr ng-repeat-start="tempLocation in regions.locations"> </tr>
            <tr>
                <td rowspan=""4>{{regions.regionName}}</td>

                <td rowspan="2">
                    <table>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr ng-repeat-start="location in regions.locations">
                                <td> {{location.locationname}}</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr ng-repeat-end></tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </td>

                <td >
                    <table>
                        <tbody ng-repeat="router in tempLocation.routers">
                            <tr>
                                <td>{{router.routername}}</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </td>

            </tr>

            <tr ng-repeat-end></tr> 
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: SHare what you have tried in form of a demo of plunkr.com

Comment: I have added what i have tried , please look into it @Shashank Vivek

Comment: Mark it as an answer with an upvote if it helped ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here a sample [plunkr to help you out](https://plnkr.co/edit/QCq8D4RbGvh3N7YmBKEj?p=preview)

```
<table id="customers">
  <thead>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th> Regions </th>
      <th> Location </th>
      <th> Routers </th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="data in dataList">
       <td>{{data.regionName}}</td>
       <td>
        <table>
           <tr ng-repeat="location in data.locations">
             <td>{{location.locationname}}</td>
           </tr>
        </table>
       </td>
       <td>
         <table>
           <tr ng-repeat="location in data.locations">
             <td>
               <table>
                  <tr ng-repeat="route in location.routers">
                    <td>{{route.routername}}</td>
                  </tr>
               </table>
             </td>
           </tr>
        </table>
       </td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Just check for the css styles to make it look similar to what you are seeing in the code. Also see if `div` could be a better choice than `table` , its upto you

Comment: Thanks for the help